# How to commit a credential template to github

Tags: python, git, commit, secret-key

I am working on a project where i am accessing an API. I have a python file that has variables to the API key and secret. I want to commit it to GitHub without having those variables filled out. What would be the best way to do it without having to remove the key each time? Let me know if i need to clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use environment variables and access them with `os.environ.get('your var')`

Comment: You could add it to the `.gitignore` and add an example file without the credentials.

Comment: Thank you both. I will try those things.